# Cannot download file from storage folder in laravel 5.4

Tags: laravel-5

I have store the file in storage/app/files folder by `$path=$request->file->store('files')` and save the path "files/LKaOlKhE5uITzAbRj5PkkNunWldmUTm3tOWPfLxO.doc" it in a table's column name `file`.

I have also linked storage folder to public through `php artisan storage:link`.

In my view blade file, I put this

```
<a href="@if(count($personal_information)) {{asset('storage/'.$personal_information->file)}} @endif" download>Download File</a>
```

and the link for download file is `http://localhost:8000/storage/files/LKaOlKhE5uITzAbRj5PkkNunWldmUTm3tOWPfLxO.doc`

But I get the error

> NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161

If I add `/app` after the `/storage` it gives the same error. How can I download file from my `storage/app/files` folder?

Comment: refer to [Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31648243/laravel-5-notfoundhttpexception-in-routecollection-php-line-143)

Comment: This will help you......... [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43315857/cannot-download-file-from-storage-folder-in-laravel-5-4)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Problem is **storage** folder is not publicly accessible in default. Storage folder is most likely forsave some private files such as  users pictures which is not accessible by other users. If you move them to public folder files will be accessible for everyone. I had similar issue with Laravel 5.4 and I did a small go around by writing a route to download files.

```
Route::get('files/{file_name}', function($file_name = null)
{
    $path = storage_path().'/'.'app'.'/files/'.$file_name;
    if (file_exists($path)) {
        return Response::download($path);
    }
});
```

Or you can save your files into **public** folder up to you.

Comment: where does the Response:: came from?

Comment: @GrizzlyBear you can add it as use in you controller `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Response;`

Answer (score 2):

I'm using Laravel 6.X and was having a similar issue. The go around according to your issue is as follows:
1)In your **routes/web.php** do something like

```
/**sample route**/
Route::get('/download/{path}/', 'MyController@get_file');
```

2)Then in your controller (**MyController.php**) for our case it should look like this:

```php
    <?php
    
    namespace App\Http\Controllers;
    
    use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
    
    class MyController extends Controller
    {
        public function get_file($path)
        {
            /**this will force download your file**/
            return response()->download($path);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have your files is stored in the public directory then use: **public_path()**. But if your files are stored in the storage directory, then use: **storage_path()**

**NOTE:** If your storage folder contains only attachment folder then consider having it this way: `storage_path('photos/');`

`$destination = storage_path('storage/photos/'); 
               or
$destination = public_path('storage/photos/');
$filename = "user_3423423465.png";
$pathToFile = $destination.$filename;
return response()->download($pathToFile,'user_profile_photo.png');`

Answer (score -1):

Laravel8

Create a link

```
<a href="{{ url('download?path='. $user->avatar) }}">
    Download
</a>
```

Define a route

```
Route::get('download', [DownloadController::class,'download']);
```

Handle it

```
public function download(Request $request){
    return Storage::download($request->path);
}
```

Answer (score -2):

**For Laravel 8**

Upload File to Storage Folder

in this example, i have created a test folder inside storage folder **name: uploadedfiles**

In **FileSystem.php**

```
'uploadedfiles' => [
   'driver' => 'local',
   'root' => storage_path('uploadedfiles'),
],
```

**Upload File**

```
public function upload_file()
{
  $file_name = "files_"."_".strtotime("now")."_".$_FILES['file']['name'];
  $content = file_get_contents($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']);
  Storage::disk('uploadedfiles')->put($file_name,$content);
}
```

**Download File** from Storage Folder

```
Route::get('download/files/{filename}', function($filename) {
  $file = Storage::disk('uploadedfiles')->download($filename);
  return $file;
});
```

Comment: This does not work. I have tested it on my end.