# how to download file from storage folder in blade page in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, storage

Here is the code:

```
<a download="MyPdf" href="{{ storage('app/public/file.pdf') }}" title="MyPdf">Download</a>
```

The file.pdf are in the folder storage/app/public

Comment: try this :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43315857/cannot-download-file-from-storage-folder-in-laravel-5-4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to create a symbolic link

```
php artisan storage:link
```

That will create a symbolic link to `/storage/app/public`

After you need use `Storage::url()`;

**Example:**

```
<a download="MyPdf" href="{{ Storage::url('file.pdf') }}" title="MyPdf">Download</a>
```

With this you will download what is in the `/storage/app/public/file.pdf` folder

Answer (score 0):

1. add url like

   ```
   Route::get('get/file', function(){
       return Storage::download('path to file');
   })
   ```
2. now hit the url and you will download the file