# How to download file from storage?

Tags: php, laravel, storage

I'm using Laravel's file storage system and I'm trying to trigger a download response to download my files through the browser, but it cant find the correct file instead it downloads my file page view script. I have a storage link set up as well.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

File.blade.php

```
 @extends('layouts.app')

 @section('content')


 <div class="container">
  <form action="{{route('upload')}}" method="POST" 
  enctype="multipart/form-data" name="formName"> 
{{csrf_field() }}
     <input type="file" name="file">
     <input type="submit" class="btn" name="submit">
</form>
<div class="row">
@foreach($files as $file)
   <a href="{{route('download',$file)}}" download="{{$file->name}}"> 
   {{$file->name}}</a>

 </div>
 </div>

 @endsection
```

Download function

```
public function download($file){


    return response()->download(storage_path('/storage/app/files/'.$file));
 }
```

file routes

```
  Route::get('files', 'FileController@index')->name('upload');
  Route::post('files', 'FileController@store');
  Route::get('files/{file}', 'FileController@download')->name('download');
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43315857/cannot-download-file-from-storage-folder-in-laravel-5-4

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove this  `download="{{$file->name}}"` from the link.
You can add `download` as html attribute:

```
<a href="{!! route('download', $file->name) !!}" download>{{ $file->name }}</a>
```

But you don't need it in this case, use just:

```
<a href="{!! route('download', $file->name) !!}">{{$file->name}}</a>
```

The `response()->download()` method in your controller will generate a response that forces the  browser to download the file at the given path. So make sure your path i correct.
If your file is in `your-project-root-path/storage/app/files/`, you can use:

```
return response()->download(storage_path('/app/files/'. $file));
```

If your file is in `your-project-root-path/storage/storage/app/files/`, use:

```
return response()->download(storage_path('/storage/app/files/'. $file));
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are passing the file object instead of the filename to your download route.
Try

```
 @extends('layouts.app')

 @section('content')


 <div class="container">
  <form action="{{route('upload')}}" method="POST" 
  enctype="multipart/form-data" name="formName"> 
{{csrf_field() }}
     <input type="file" name="file">
     <input type="submit" class="btn" name="submit">
</form>
<div class="row">
@foreach($files as $file)
   <a href="{{route('download',$file->name)}}" download> 
   {{$file->name}}</a>

 </div>
 </div>

 @endsection
```

Try replacing {{route('download',$file)}} with {{route('download',$file->name)}}.
Also try replacing the download controller with this code

```
public function download($file){
    return response()->download(storage_path('app/files/'.$file));
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public function jpg_download($id)
{
    if (auth()->user()->download_count < 5) {

        auth()->user()->increment('download_count');
        $data = DB::table('products')->where('id', $id)->first();
        $path = public_path('/storage/item/jpg/' . $data->jpg);
        return response()->download($path);
    }
    dd('Next Day Download');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I use Laravel v9, and I use Storage to download a file from local storage (visibility = private):

```
public function download(): StreamedResponse
{
    return Storage::disk('disk_name')->download(
        $pathToAFile,
        $downloadedFileName
    );
}
```

After clicking a link, a file is downloaded.